# OpenBDT - Framework de Automação de Testes

Tags: testes-automatizados

Gostaria de mais informações sobre esse novo FW de automação utilizando o conceito de BDT.

Aonde posso fazer o download e utilizar? É OpenSource?

Answer (score 2):

No site do próprio OpenBDT ([openbdt.io](http://openbdt.io), lançado hoje, você pode encontrar mais informações, e inclusive encontrar o link do `GitHub` do projeto para download. E sim! É um Framework Open Source.